# Problema con funcion js en Móviles

Tags: php, javascript, html

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo el siguiente código que va de maravilla en la pc

```js
function myFunction(var1,var2){
  swal({
      title: 'Alerta!',
      text: 'aceptas?',
      icon: 'warning',
      buttons: ['No Aceptar', 'Aceptar'],
  })
  .then((willAccept) => {
      if (willAccept) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'Aceptar.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'html',
            data :  {aceptar: willAccept, var1: var1, var2: var2},
        })
        .done(function(resultado){
            swal(resultado);
            setTimeout(function(){
              window.location.href = "index.php";
            }, 2000)
        });
      }
  });
}
```

lo mando a llamar de la siguiente manera desde un documento php:

```html
<div align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction('.$idVar1.','.$idVar2.')">Aceptar</button></div><br>
```

la duda es por que no me funciona en móviles alguien me puede explicar por favor que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, o a que se debe este error, lo repito una vez mas en pc me anda de perlas sin ningún error pero en móviles al dar click en el botón no hace nada.

Comment: verifica con otra version del navegador, o por lo menos con una mas reciente para android

Comment: Es tan simple como que mobiles no tienes mouse y no reconoce bien el `onclick` su contraparte es touch `ontouchstart`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ponerle comillas dobles a las variables en la llamada a la función.

```php
<div align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction('.'"'.$idVar1.'"'.','.'"'.$idVar2.'"'.')">
```

Yo personalmente prefiero pasar este tipo de cosas en un data y cogerlos en JavaScript.

```php
<div align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-var1="'.$idVar1.'" data-var2="'.$idVar1.'" onclick="myFunction()">
```

```
function myFunction(){
    var var1 = this.dataset.var1;
    var var2 = this.dataset.var2;
}
```